# Exclude two last week mysql

Tags: mysql, request

Good morning,

I am on a MySQL database and I have the following query which extracts data from the last 6 months to today's date :

```
select distinct
            date_format(abc.date,'%d/%m/%Y') as date_bes
 from table abc
 where   abc.date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL  2 WEEK
```

I want to change my query to the last 6 months, excluding the last current week.

For example I want to exclude week 11 which is from March 13 to March 19
and week 12 which is the current week: from March 20 to 26.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows :

```
select distinct
            date_format(abc.date,'%d/%m/%Y') as date_bes
 from table abc
 where   abc.date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())) DAY) - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
```

to get the first day of the week starting from sunday : `DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())) DAY)`

to get the first day of the week starting from monday : `DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL(-WEEKDAY(CURDATE())) DAY);`

In this case we need to get data till sunday 2023-03-12

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WEEKDAY()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) which:

> Returns the weekday index for date (0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday, … 6 = Sunday).

We use +1 to go back to the Sunday, and another +7 to go back another week.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(abc.date,'%d/%m/%Y') AS date_bes
FROM table abc
WHERE abc.date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH
                   AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) + 8) DAY
```

This solution and the one provided by SelVazi provide slightly different results. I am not sure which you want so here is a table showing the differences:

| CURDATE() | this one | SelVazi |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-18 | 2023-03-05 | 2023-03-05 |
| 2023-03-19 | 2023-03-05 | 2023-03-12 |
| 2023-03-20 | 2023-03-12 | 2023-03-12 |
| 2023-03-21 | 2023-03-12 | 2023-03-12 |
| 2023-03-22 | 2023-03-12 | 2023-03-12 |
| 2023-03-23 | 2023-03-12 | 2023-03-12 |
| 2023-03-24 | 2023-03-12 | 2023-03-12 |
| 2023-03-25 | 2023-03-12 | 2023-03-12 |
| 2023-03-26 | 2023-03-12 | 2023-03-19 |
| 2023-03-27 | 2023-03-19 | 2023-03-19 |